# Contact_level__c doesn't exist

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have mini project for salesforce intership, so d did this code:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        Contact cont = new Contact(
            FirstName = 'Name' + i,
            LastName = 'Surname' + i,
            Email = 'e' + i + '@mail.com'
        );
        
        if(i < 65) {
            cont.AccountId = accA.Id;
            cont.Contact_Level__c = 'Primary';
        } else if(i < 130) {
            cont.AccountId = accB.Id;
            cont.Contact_Level__c = 'Secondary';
        } else {
            cont.AccountId = accC.Id;
            cont.Contact_Level__c = 'Tertiary';
        }
        
        testContactList.add(cont);
    }
    
    insert testContactList;
}
```

And mistake is Variable does not exist: Contact_Level__c
But i really don't know what the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have a field with that name on `Contact` table? No typos? Maybe it's called `ContactLevel__c` or `Level__c`?
Go to setup -> customize -> contacts -> fields (or Setup -> Object manager -> Contact -> fields if you're in Lightning) and double check?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the API name (ContactLevel__c) you mentioned in the code is not right means there may be typo mistake or the variable does not even exist.
You can go to Setup --> Object Manager --> Contact --> Fields and Relationship and search for the field, if the field is present copy the API name and paste it into the code.
Hope this solves your problem.